# Find area of a crescent

Tags: circles, area

Find the area of the shaded region that is enclosed by a full circle and a quarter circle inscribed in a square.
[image]

My math teacher gave me this question as a challenge. But I can't seem to solve it. Can you guys help? Please tell me the steps to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You need to present this as a better question rather than a rough diagram in an image.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Assume unit square. The area is $A_{square}-A_{purple}-A_{green}-2A_{grey}$, i.e.

$$Area 
=\frac34 - \frac{3\pi}{16} -2A_{grey} \tag1
$$

where $A_{grey}$ can be obtained by evaluating the areas of the circular sectors ABP, OPE, and the triangles AFP and FPO; then subtracting them from the half square, as done below.

Let the vertex A being the origin, the polar equation of the two circles are $r=1; \space \space r(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)=r^2+\frac{1}{4}$. Eliminate $r$ to obtain $\sin\beta = \frac{5+\sqrt{7}}{8}$ and then
$\sin\alpha =\frac{\sqrt{7}-1}{4}$. The area of two triangles AFP and FPO is

$$A_q = \frac{1}{4}\sin\beta +  \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\cos\beta \right)=\frac{2+\sqrt{7}}{16}
$$

and the area of the two circular sectors is

$$A_c=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\beta\right) + \frac{\alpha}{8}
=\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{1}{8}\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{23\sqrt{7}+67}{128}\right). $$

As a result,

$$A_{grey}=\frac{1}{2}-A_c-A_q=\frac{6-\sqrt{7}-2\pi}{16}+\frac{1}{8}\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{23\sqrt{7}+67}{128}\right) $$
Substitute into (1) to obtain

$$Area = \frac{\pi+2\sqrt7}{16} - \frac{1}{4}\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{23\sqrt{7}+67}{128}\right)$$

Comment: Impressive! BTW, I got the same result as yours

Answer (score 0):

Assuming unitary square, the demicircles have equations
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{x-x^2}+1\right);\;y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Intersection point is at $x_1=\frac{1}{8} \left(5-\sqrt{7}\right)$

Intersections with the diagonal are at $$x_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};\;x_3=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)$$

The requested area is twice the area colored in the picture below that is
$$A/2=\int_{{x_1}}^{{x_2}}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{x-x^2}+1\right)-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\,dx+\int_{{x_2}}^{{x_3}}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{x-x^2}+1\right)-x\right)\,dx$$
$$A=\frac{1}{16} \left(2 \sqrt{7}-5 \pi +16 \arcsin \left(\frac{1}{8} \left(5-\sqrt{7}\right)\right)+8 \text{ arcsec}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\sqrt{7}+5}}{3}\right)\right)\approx 0.14638$$

---

$$..$$

[image]